# Product Out of Stock Auto-respond

Tags: bigcommerce, auto-responder

Bigcommerce Store Scenario: A product that a customer would like to purchase is out of stock. Is there a way to have the customer provide an e-mail address to automatically notify the customer that the product is available again?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: only creating an app using webhooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This already exists as an app for Bigcommerce called "[In Stock Notify](https://www.bigcommerce.com/apps/instocknotify-inventory-management-buyer-solution/)" since it isn't available as current functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

No, Bigcommerce does not have that feature built in.

The only workaround is to develop an app to do it using the Bigcommerce API.